# Bootstrap 3 Progress Bar on top of an image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would like to use bootstrap 3's built in progress bar :

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

But place it on top of image, like a thermometer for example.

I'm not sure where to start or if I should just not use bootstraps progress bar for this.

Comment: Use position relative (parent(Image)) and position absolute  (child(thermometer ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use absolute positioning.

Using this method, it's important for the outer container to have a position:relative, so that child elements have an absolute position "relative" to the container rather than the whole page.  Make the container the same size as the image x & y, and position just make the image position absolutely at 0,0.  Then, position the progress bar somewhere that looks good.

```
<div id='outer-container' style='position:relative;width:x;height:y;'>

    <img style='position:absolute;width:x;height:y;z-index:0;' />

    <div class="progress" style='position:absolute;top:{halfy};left:0;z-index:1;'>
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        60%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way would be to make the image a background image, and then place the progress bar inside the tag that has the background-image.  This way it will overlay and you don't necessarily need to do absolute positioning tweaks.